# HTML TinyMCE does not display

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce

I am using [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php) but It does not display I get this error and do not know how to fix this problem.

Failed to load: ~/Scripts/tinyMCE/js/tinymce/plugins/moxiemanager/api.php?action=language&tinymce=true&code=auto

I am using MVC 4

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <p>
        Write something in TinyMCE:
        <textarea name="content" style="width: 100%"></textarea>
    </p>
</div
```

**Script**

```
<script src="../../Scripts/tinyMCE/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>
<script src="../../Scripts/tinyMCE/js/tinymce/plugins/moxiemanager/plugin.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        plugins: [
          "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
          "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
          "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste moxiemanager"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to remove the moxiemanager from the plugin list.

It should work then.

Comment: It works thank you but I need moxiemanager to add images to the content?

Comment: in this case you need to make sure it is at the right location (usually the plugins directory) and it is the tinymce v4 compatible version

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem, cannot load the api.php.  It works like a champ in the local environment, but the server doesn't even load TinyMCE.  After running about for a long time I found the solution to be rather simple!

My asset folder's permissions were set to 777, which was being rejected on the server.
Make sure your permissions aren't too loose, 755 is my server's magic number, though you may need 766.